# Can I have Visual Studio IDE auto-comple brackets?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, ide

Suppose I have a line of code that starts like the following:

```
Func1(Func2(Func3
```

Is it possible to set up Visual Studio (2005, 2008, 2010) IDE, so that when I hit ';' it will auto-complete all the brackets. I am only interested in brackets, nothing fancier. It doesn't have to be ';' key, it can be another key that auto-completes both brackets and ';'. This is a tiny thing that pops-up time and time again, and I've always wondered if I had to live with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [CodeRush](http://devexpress.com), or implement your own add-in...

Comment: Is there a way to activate this capability in CodeRush Xpress? While I would normally approve of all these answers for personal use (both CodeRush and Resharper), in the work place it takes months for legal to even get back to you if you can proceed with purchase. So if Xpress has it, I'm all set, if it doesn't I will have to implement my own plug-in (in order to have it before retirement time). Any pointers for the plug-in development?

Answer (score 3):

You could also check out Resharper: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/
Once you go Resharper, you can't go back. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also, Telerik has a product called JustCode that can do these sorts of things too.